# Minecraft Recipe Book not working in multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently installed minecraft 1.12 and it's great, especially the recipe book.  I generally play with my child and the book is a big help.

However, in multiplayer, the recipe book doesn't work correctly.  When clicking a recipe, it briefly loads it into the crafting window then automatically clears it without creating the item.  See this video for an example:  https://streamable.com/74c2u

Is this a known issue and is there a fix for it?

Comment: 1. Is your connection good? Maybe it's just lag. 2. Try to restart Minecraft. 3. Does this also happen under other circumstances, for example on other servers?

Comment: This is on internal lan.  Less than 10 ms latency.  Running my Spigot on my own linux server.

Comment: Found the solution. Posting here is anyone else runs into the problem. Thanks everyone for the guidance. https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/allowing-players-to-use-recipe-book-craft-assist.259532/

Comment: Does this also happen on servers without Spigot?

Comment: @kalebr Just an FYI that answers which are just a link aren't allowed on Arqade (links go dead all the time) which is why I converted your answer to a comment. I'd encourage you to post a new answer, though, where you summarize the information found in the link.

Comment: @kalebr Did one of the answers solve your question? If yes, please mark it as accepted, so that this question doesn't remain open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a glitch that can be used to duplicate items.  The server you are on may be causing that issue to prevent the glitch from being possible until the problem is fixed correctly.  You might check with the server website or administration and see if that is the case.

---

Edit:
This is not my answer.  It is the answer you get if you follow the link provided by kalebr in the comments.  In case his link goes down.

Give the permission `minecraft.autocraft` to allow players to use the recipe book.

Be warned, at the time of this edit, the duplication glitch is still functioning so allowing players to use autocraft enables them to duplicate items.  This includes stacking items that normally can not be stacked(totems, armor, tools, etc)

Comment: It's my own server, but basically a "stock" server created using Spigot Buildtools.

Answer (score -1):

same here!
After a bit of research, it seems to be a duplication bug on spigot servers. 
here is a video for the bug:

and here is the actual bug report: 
https://hub.spigotmc.org/jira/projects/SPIGOT/issues/SPIGOT-3466?filter=allopenissues

Comment: That's why you shouldn't rely on external links for your answer: The video is no longer available.